# Storing text file in structured array

Tags: regex, matlab, io

I have an input text file which is well structured:

```
START_PARAMETERS
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bladed_wind_generator\_wind
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bladed_wind_generator\reference_v_4_2.$PJ
END_PARAMETERS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
START_DLC1-2
4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 29
6
8192
600
END_DLC1-2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
START_DLC6-1
44.8
30
8192
600
END_DLC6-1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
START_DLC6-4
3 31 33 35
6
8192
600
END_DLC6-4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
START_DLC7-2
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 
6
8192
600
END_DLC7-2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At the moment I read it this way:

```
clc,clear all,close all

f = fopen('inp.txt','rt');  % Read Input File
C = textscan(f, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\r\n');
C = C{1}; % Store Input File in a Cell
fclose(f);
```

Then, by means of regexp I read every occurrence of (START_DLC/END_DLC) block:

```
startIndx = regexp(C,'START_DLC','match');
endIndx = regexp(C,'END_DLC','match');
```

The aim is to store the content of the text between each START_DLC/END_DLC block in a structured cell(supposed to be called store_DLCs). The result has to be(e.g. DLC1-2):

```
DLC1-2
4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 29
6
8192
600
```

and so on until DLC7-2.

Would you mind to give me some hints how to proceed?

I thank you all in advance.

BR,
Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code so far is okay. One thing though, I'd slightly alter your computation of `startIndx` and `endIndx` to the following:

```
startIndx = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C, 'START_DLC', 'match')));
endIndx = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(C, 'END_DLC', 'match')));
```

so that you would get *actual* indices (I've transposed them here for visual convenience), like so:

```
startIndx =

     6    13    20    27


endIndx =

    11    18    25    32
```

I'd also add an assertion to check the integrity of the input:

```
assert(all(size(startIndx) == size(endIndx)))
```

Now, with all the indices computed as above, you can proceed to extract the data into cells:

```
extract_dlc = @(n)({C{startIndx(n):endIndx(n) - 1}});
store_DLCs = arrayfun(extract_dlc, 1:numel(startIndx), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

And to "fix" the names (which are first entries) of each cell, you can do:

```
fix_dlc_name = @(x){strrep(x{1}, 'START_', ''), x{2:end}};
store_DLCs = cellfun(fix_dlc_name, store_DLCs,  'UniformOutput', false);
```

This code applied on your example input would yield a 1-by-4 cell array of cells:

```
store_DLCs =

    {'DLC1-2', '4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 29', '6', '8192', '600'}  
    {'DLC6-1', '44.8', '30', '8192', '600'}   
    {'DLC6-4', '3 31 33 35', '6', '8192', '600'}   
    {'DLC7-2', '2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24', '6', '8192', '600'}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable help; I will need some time to completely get into regexp. What you suggested is worth solution to my question.

Comment: I have another easy to solve question: I would like arrays of numbers (e.g. 44.8, 30, 8192, 600 for DLC6-1) to be read as numbers and not as char. Instead DLCx-y can stay as string. I would use str2num, but perhaps there is an easier way to achieve the same results. Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Well, you cannot possible know which line you're reading (the `START_DLC`/`END_DLC` strings, or numbers). I believe you are forced to read each line as a string, and then convert it to numerical values as necessary.