# importing demarcated blocks of a file into distinct cells of an array

Tags: matlab, import, cell-array

I have an input file having the following basic structure:

```
    master header line(s)
     block 1 header line(s)
      ... [m' x n] numerical matrix ...
     block 2 header line(s)
      ... [m'' x n] numerical matrix ...
           ...
     block N header line(s)
      ... [m(N) x n] numerical matrix ...
```

where `n` is constant, but `m` may assume different values (as indicated by the prime marks).

I am wondering if there is a simple way to load data of this organization into a cell array (or another structure of some kind) having the following form: each block of data (as defined by the header) is represented by a cell in a cell array, the contents of which are the numerical data in the form of a double array. To concretize that description, the desired MATLAB representation would appear as follows: cell{1} contains a double array containing the numerical data listed under the block 1 header; cell{2} contains a double array containing the numerical data listed under the block 2 header; etc.

Of course, there are simple alternatives, such as splitting the input file into individual block-specific files and sequentially reading each file into an element of a cell array via a loop statement, but I am interested to know whether there is a solution that does not require such manipulation.

Comment: Is the file ASCII or binary? Guessing text.

Comment: ASCII: header lines are text; data lines are tab-delimited real numbers

Comment: I just noticed multiple header lines...

Comment: There is some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352737/parsing-text-file-in-matlab)

Comment: @sebas: Thank you for the link. I ended up following the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12248524/873757) in a related post.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar.  One way, as you say, is to divide  into files.  But really, since your file has a set structure:

```
1 - open the file
2 - read the first line (e.g. using fget)
3 - Read the header (e.g. using fget)
4 - read the next M rows (e.g. using fget, fread, etc.) and store as a matrix
5 - loop back to 3 except when eof.
```

(apologies for the pseudocode, I don't have access to Matlab on this computer)

Yes, this is still manipulation of the file, but it becomes extendable to when the file isn't as ordered as the example you gave (which is the case I have), and is extremely easy to read and debug.  However, it will be slow if your file is hundreds of MBs.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I made an oversight in my post, which is that the mxn matrices do not have constant values for m (n, however, is constant). How could step 4 of your pseudocode be adjusted to accommodate this variation?

Comment: There are a couple of ways.  First, do your headers have any common text (i.e. will they have some symbol at the beginning, or a common word, such as "header")?  If so, then you can look for it using strfind.  If not, then you can check the first character of the line you have just read - if it is a character, then it is a header.  If not, then it is a line of N values, in which case you can divide it up (or you can reread the line using textscan).  Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, all my headers contain a string that distinguishes them from the numeric arrays. Do you think it would be faster to read the entire file first, and parse later, or to read line by line, checking each to determine whether the line is a header or not? My input file is about 100 to 200 MB.

Comment: I ended up adapting [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12248524/873757). Thanks again for your suggested approach.